# load applicationContext in Java web project (Not MVC)

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

Fairly new to Spring, in stand alone applications,i have seen the following:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "SpringBeans.xml");
```

But in web application i have not seen this approach of creating using a new keyword.
How do we achieve the same in Web app ?

Comment: Please see the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: this refers to mvc, what i meant is, for a java j2ee webproject , whenn i integrate spring, how can i load the beans without calilng new ClassPathXmlApplicationContex

Comment: In the reference documentation, you can see how you can achieve this. First define context loader listener in web.xml and specify your spring-bean.xml in context param. So when the sever starts, the context loader loads the spring configuration file. This is just some basic info. You have go through the documentation if you want to know Web based application with Spring.