# Different objects created for each controller request in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, controller, singleton

Tried something- Crated a simple Spring mvc app,i have a controller class. I read in the spring docs that controller class is singe tone and a single instance is created,But that is not the case when i tried out.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    String message = "Welcome to your 1st Maven Spring project !";
    @Autowired
    private Person person;
     String ok="ok";

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String test() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("word s "+ok);
        System.out.println("from controller");
        System.out.println(person.getName());
        new TestController().ok="changed.";
```

here i accessed the hello url from different browser, i am getting "ok" printed, even though i change it in the test method, 
Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not changing it. You're creating a new controller, and changing the field of that new controller.

Replace

```
new TestController().ok="changed.";
```

by

```
ok = "changed.";
```

(and make the `ok` variable volatile, otherwise there is still a chance that another thread sees the old value, although that is unlikely).

Comment: Made my day, thnx.

Comment: haveone. More doubt can u take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725862/